# Convert/Cast Array to Integer in python

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

The following code:

```
polygon_test = spark.sql("""SELECT
  CAST(geojson4.geometry AS Double) AS geometry
 ,geojson4.properties
 ,geojson4.type
FROM geojson4
""")
```

Produces the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;CAST(geojson4.`geometry` AS DOUBLE)&#39; due to data type mismatch: cannot cast struct&lt;coordinates:array&lt;array&lt;array&lt;string&gt;&gt;&gt;,type:string&gt; to double; line 2 pos 2;
```

The error is clearly because databricks is unable to cast `geometry` field as a double.

Can someone let me know if its possiblet cast ARRAYs as any number. In its raw format it appears as string, see below

geometry:struct
coordinates:array
element:array
element:array
element:string
type:string
properties:struct
lat_max:double
lat_min:double
long_max:double
long_min:double
pid:long
type:string

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast array as a number, but you can extract values from the array using the square brackets, like this:

```
SELECT geojson4.geometry[0] AS geometry,
   geojson4.properties, geojson4.type
FROM geojson4
```

but you need to know what element you're extracting - first, second, etc.